# Prove $\ \int_a^b fd\alpha =0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, riemann-integration

By definition, prove that, if $ \alpha$ in$ [a,b]$ is defined as

$\alpha(x) =   \begin{cases} 
      1 & x = c \\
      0 &  x \neq c
   \end{cases}
$

where$ c \in (a,b)$ and f is continuous on c, then$\ \int_a^b fd\alpha =0$

**Attempt**

My definition for a Riemman-Stieltjes sum is, for P a partition of [a,b] then
$$\ S(P,f,\alpha) = \sum_{k=q}^ n f(t_k)\Delta\alpha_k $$

Since $c\in(a,b)$ we take a partition of $ [a,b]$, $$P=(a,x_1,...,x_{j-1},c,x_{j+1},...,x_{n-1},b)$$

From this, we see that

$$\ S(P,f,\alpha) = \sum_{k=q}^ n f(t_k)\Delta\alpha_k = 0$$

Since f is continuous in c, by definition we have that 
$$ |x-c|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$$

So we choose $P_{\epsilon}$ such that $ ||P_{\epsilon}||<\delta$ and we'll have that $ ||P||≤||P_{\epsilon}||<\delta$

If we choose $ \int_a^b fd\alpha = 0$ then

$$ |S(P,f,\alpha) - \int_a^b fd\alpha| = 0 < \epsilon$$

therefore, $ \int_a^b fd\alpha = 0$.

Is this a correct aprroach?

Comment: If you need a final hint $|f(t_{j+1}) - f({t_j})| \leqslant |f(t_{j+1}) - f({c})| + |f(c) - f({t_j})| $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic approach and statement about $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ is correct, but it is not clear how this implies that the integral is $0$. Furthermore, $S(P,f,\alpha) \neq 0$, in general,  for your chosen partition.

If $c$ is not an endpoint of a subinterval $[x_{k-1},x_k]$ of the partition $P$, then for all $k = 1,\ldots,n$ we have $\alpha(x_k) - \alpha(x_{k-1}) = 0$. In this case, $S(P,f,\alpha) = 0$ and $|S(P,f,\alpha)-0| < \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0.$

Otherwise, suppose $c  = x_j$. We then have

$$S(P,f,\alpha) = f(t_j)(\alpha(c) - \alpha(x_{j-1})) + f(t_{j+1})(\alpha(x_{j+1}) - \alpha(c)) = f(t_j) - f(t_{j+1})$$

Now fill in the steps to show that the continuity of $f$ implies

$$|S(P,f,\alpha)-0| = |f(t_j) - f(t_{j+1})| < \epsilon$$

if $\|P\|$ is sufficiently small.

Comment: But it is given that $ c \in (a,b)$, that's why c is not an endpoint of the interval

Comment: I edited. I mean if $c$ is not an endpoint of a partition subinterval $[x_{k-1},x_k]$.

Comment: We get very different results for $S(P,f,\alpha)$ depending on if $c$ is one of the interior endpoints.  If it is not then $\alpha(x_k) - \alpha(x_{k-1}) = 0 - 0$ for all $k = 1, \ldots, n$. Otherwise, there are two subintervals where $\Delta \alpha_k = \pm 1$.

Comment: I was a little sleepy yesterday, now I figured it out, thanks for your help

Comment: @DavidTomahawk: You're welcome.